# Can't declare object

Tags: c++

I am getting an error on this line:

```
Attack a("Nothing", 60, Magic);
```

Here is the error:

```
..\main.cpp:11: error: expected `;' before "a"
..\main.cpp:11: warning: statement has no effect
```

Here are the relevant files:
main.cpp:

```
#include "Attack.h"

int main() {
    Attack a("Nothing", 60, Magic);

    return 0;
}
```

Attack.h:

```
#ifndef ATTACK_H_
#define ATTACK_H_

#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum ATTACK_ATTRIBUTE {
    Attack, Speed, Magic
};

class Attack {
private:
    std::string name;
    int power; //Out of 10
    ATTACK_ATTRIBUTE attribute;

public:
    Attack(std::string name, int power, ATTACK_ATTRIBUTE attribute);
    virtual ~Attack();

    std::string getName();

    ATTACK_ATTRIBUTE getAttribute();

    int getPower();
};

#endif /* ATTACK_H_ */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a class and an enumerator both called 'Attack'.  Try changing one of the names to something else.

Comment: Yeah, and usually **enums** are defined with CAPS LOCK on to avoid this kind of thing!

Comment: Also, thanks Cat Plus Plus for catching my sloppy use of terminology!  I think I was still somewhere in ML land and wanting to say 'datatype constructor', but it ended up somewhere halfway between.

Comment: ...or start enum names with an abbreviation (eg AA_Attack), put in a namespace or use enum class (latest C++ only)

Comment: @karlphillip: I would not say this is the "usual" practice, even though it is common. Personnaly, I prefer encapsulating the enum into a class to keep the enumerators from "leaking" in the enclosing scope (and will now use C++11 `enum class`es).

Comment: I agree with karlphillip's assertion that it is usual practice, in my experience, at least.

Comment: I guess it all depends on our definitions of "usual" :). For the record, Boost libraries sometimes use upper case and sometimes lower case, Qt's enumerators are all CamelCase, the Google style guide advocates CamelCase with a prefix (although they also acceptate upper case), the NASA style guide enforces upper case, etc. As you can see, there is no consensus, hence my claim that it is not a convention universally agreed upon (is there any such convention when it comes to coding style...?). But I suppose I must have given a too strong meaning to the word "usual" :).

Answer (score 2):

The enum value Attack is in the same namespace as Attack the class and they are conflicting.

Answer (score -1):

You have defined your Attack class in a header file but I don't see an implementation for it. Don't you need to implement the class methods?

Comment: I did I just didn't include it because it was not relevant

Comment: Ah okay. Looks like other folks have answered.